# How do I change python code below to calculate and output the sum of all digits of the input number, based on the problem below?

Tags: python

How do I change the python code below to calculate and output the sum of all digits of the input number, based on the problem below?

```
n = int(input())
length = 0

while n > 0:
    n //= 10
    length += 1
    print(length)
```

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: Which "problem below"?

Comment: You'd want `length += n % 10` but I'd instead call it `total` since that's more accurate. You'd also want to do that *before* dividing by 10 or you'll be off by a digit

Answer (score 0):

```py
n = input()
sum = 0

for char in n:
    if char.isdigit():
        sum += int(char)

print(sum)
```

Comment: I keep getting this with your suggestion: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usercode/file0.py", line 6, in <module>
    sum += char
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: @captaincaveman1729 oops … I should test my code before posting it - should work now

Comment: Thanks so much! it worked. I'm very new to python and coding at large, so now I have to understand what you did... good problems!

Comment: @captaincaveman1729 I will add some comments later